# Taking specific value from the CSV file using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Let's say I want a last specific value from the CSV file. THis is my code.

When I run this code, it gives me the value saying "2 Ana"

What can I do here to just get the value 'Ana'?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

CSV_file = pd.read_csv('appl.csv')


name = CSV_file['Name']

v_val = name.iloc[-1:]

print(v_val)
```

THe CSV file is this:

```
Name,Age,Location
Juan,18,Lisbon
James,19,London
Ana,20,Madrid
```

I want to get the value 'Ana'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `:` from the `.iloc`:

```py
name = CSV_file["Name"].iloc[-1]
print(name)
```

Prints:

```
Ana
```

---

Or use `.iat`:

```py
name = CSV_file["Name"].iat[-1]
```